# Can I execute a windows form application programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

There's a windows form application that imports a file in a weird format, makes a lot of validation and inserts the file's data in a local SQL Server CE.

I've tried to decompile the assemblies using dotPeek but since it's a huge application I couldn't find the method neither build the application to debug.

Is it possible to fire the import function of this application programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the program and how much effort you really wish to put into doing it. For the most part though, not really.

Comment: Very sad :( But thank you, Sayse

Comment: Does this application have DLL files? Maybe what you are looking for lies on an external assembly.

Comment: @EdneyPitta - Don't get me wrong, there are ways that are used extensively with automated testing. But if your on about with code then you need to look into hooks, reading the binary, and other things that make you wonder if it was ever worth your time.

Comment: It depends a lot on how that functionality is implemented in that application. E.g. if it's a single call to a dll, you could (technically) do that from your application as well. However, that could involve complex setup or some kind of "context sensitivity" of that translation functionality that can make it next to impossible to use externally.

Comment: If whoever developed it allows you to call it through a command line argument, then yes. If not, there's no way you'll get at it. There's a tool you can use to see if this is possible while the executable is running - I don't remember the name of it off the top of my head, but I just used it..

Comment: You have a couple of options. One is writing an automated process while the application is still on. The second one would be to attach WinDBG(ProcessExplorer or ListDLLs may help as well) to the exe and see which dll(s) it is calling. If the DLLs are .NET native, then simply include them in your project and you should be able to use the methods.

Comment: Finally made it! I just added a reference to the DLL files and could be able to call the methods. There still were some errors (.config file, etc), but I generated the PDB files with dotPeek and could see where the errors stood.